# Reduce dist directory size while using sklearn.cluster.KMeans (python + py2exe)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, py2exe

I'm having a little trouble when turning my python script into an executable.
It's size is too big for me to distribute to my client.

Well, the problem is that I use just a few code of sklearn and it results in a total of 240 MB inside my distribution directory.
I know that it's not because I use only one thing that I don't need the others.
But I'm searching for a way to reduce this size, or even have an alternative to the KMeans class, with a more lightweight machine-learning package for python.

If needed, the parts of the code that use this feature are:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
...
# clus is just hanging an object instance of KMeans
clus = KMeans(n_clusters = _numBlocks, random_state = 1, n_jobs = 1)
# and here, I just call its method
_hourmap = clus.fit_predict(Load2Clus)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Well `kmeans` is a very simple algorithm and just a tiny part of `sklearn` as you recognise. I'd avoid using `sklearn` if you are constrained on memory and that is the only part of the whole package that you use. You also may not need `numpy`, `scipy` and possibly other packages unless you're using them elsewhere in your code.

Your options are:

- Implement your own version of K-means in Python.
- Use the simple `kmeans` package from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/kmeans/1.0.2) which wraps a C implementation of KMeans.
- Use the different light-weight package as you have already identified.

Other things to consider for reducing the size of your library archive are given [here](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/OptimizingSize), including:

- Excluding various external libraries
- Excluding parts of the standard library
- Compressing the archive

Which of these will suit you best depends on your program.